# how an order is matched after a fill?

Tags: trading, futures

Assuming I got a fill for an order to sell at a price ES 2018.00 but price is still at 2017.00-2017.25. What are the factor that makes the prices beetween 2017.25 and my order being filled also?

And would in that case, the price reach my sell order and traded?

Tx

Comment: do you mean that you have a filled quantity and an order to close that position at a certain price (limit sell)? Are you asking how orders in the market between the current market price and the price at which you have an order to sell are filled until it gets to your price? your question is very hard to read

Comment: Yes exactly is a sell limit. I would like to know that factor that drives the price to my sell limit. Exactly what you say.

Comment: have you looked at other questions about how market prices are determined?

Comment: I have been looking for an asnwer about this long ago, but if you have a link i will read it.

Comment: the following seems good: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3765

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In the stock market, why is the "open" price value never the same as previous day's "close"?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3765/in-the-stock-market-why-is-the-open-price-value-never-the-same-as-previous-da)

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that you just didn't see the trade, as the market ticked up and back down in seconds. You can check the time and sales data to verify. The other possibility is that it was filled as one side of a spread order, though that's not likely.