# Why is there need of open and close auction os stock exchange?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-exchanges, auction

So why is stock exchanges like nyse or nasdaq using open and close auctions for open and closing price? Why not just use previous day's closing price as today's open price and start trading from there? and what's the problem of using today's last trade's price as closing price? thanks

Comment: See [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3765/in-the-stock-market-why-is-the-open-price-value-never-the-same-as-previous-da?rq=1) and its answers.

Comment: Is there a typo in the title?